# React Reducer Updates Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I understand that in Strict Mode, the reducer should run twice. However, it shouldn't actually update the values twice.

The quantity for items gets updated twice.
For example, there is an item, `items: [{name: tshirt, price: 10, quantity: 1}]` already in the cart. If call `addItem(state, tshirt, 1)`, the cart will update to `items: [{name: tshirt, price: 10, quantity: 3}]`.

Only the quantity value inside the items array is updated twice. The outside variables such as `value` and `total_qty` only update once.

How do I stop it updating twice without turning off StrictMode?

```
interface Product {
    name: string,
    materials: string[],
    categories: string[],
    price: number,
    image?: string
}

interface ICartItem extends Product {
    quantity: number
}

interface Cart {
    items: {[key: string]: ICartItem},
    value: number,
    total_qty: number   
}

const addItem = (state: Cart, product: Product, quantity: number) => {
    let item = state?.items?.[product.name];
    if (item) {
        item.quantity += quantity;
    } else {
        item = {
            ...product,
            quantity
        }
    }
    let updatedCart = {
        ...state,
        items: {
            ...state.items,
            [product.name]: item
        },
        value: Math.max(0, state.value + (product.price * quantity)),
        total_qty: Math.max(0, state.total_qty + quantity)
    }
    return updatedCart;
}

const cartReducer: Reducer<Cart, UpdateCartAction> = (state: Cart, action: UpdateCartAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return addItem(state, action.product, action.quantity);
        case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
            return removeItem(state, action.product, action.quantity);
        case 'CLEAR_CART':
            return clearCart();
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const CartContext = React.createContext<ICartContext | undefined>(undefined);

export const CartProvider = ({children}: {children: ReactNode}) => {

    const {cart, dispatch} = useLocalStorageReducer(
        'cart',
        cartReducer,
        initialCart
    );

    const contextValue = useMemo(()=>{
        return {cart, dispatch}
    }, [cart]);

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useCart = () => {

    const contextValue = useContext(CartContext);
    let cart: Cart | undefined, dispatch: Dispatch<any> | undefined;
    if (contextValue) {
        cart = contextValue.cart;
        dispatch = contextValue.dispatch;
    }

    const addItem = (product: Product, quantity: number) => {
        if (dispatch) dispatch({type: "ADD_ITEM", product, quantity});
    }
    
    return {
        cart,
        addItem
    }

}
```

Comment: `StrictMode` makes effect hooks execute twice so where is yours and what is it doing?

Comment: How you are calling the reducer ? code you provided looks incomplete ...